# While php criando div

Tags: php, div, while

Possuo um código PHP que cria div's em while, mas deu muito trabalho para construir ele pois temos de ficar abrindo e fechando aspas no código, eu gostaria de saber se tem a possibilidade de fazer a mesma coisa só que de um jeito mais limpo e "bonito". Não acho que desta maneira esteja 100% correto, na verdade penso que está 90% errado.

```
<?php
$pasta = '../img/img_produto/';
$imagem = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);

$result_produto = "SELECT * FROM produto";
$resultado_produto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produto);
while ($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produto)) {

    echo "<div class='row border bg-color: #80006f'>" . "<div class='col-2 p-3 '>" . "<img class='Img rounded border border-primary'  src='" . $pasta . $row_produto['Img_produto'] . "'id='produto'>'" . "</div>"
    . "<div class='col-5>'" . "<div class='row'>" . "<span class='name-prod'> Nome: </span>" . $row_produto['Nome_produto'] .
    "<div class='row'>" . "<span class='desc-prod-title'> Descrição:</span>" . $row_produto['Descricao_produto'] . "</div>" . "</div>" .
    "<div class='col-2>'" . "<span class='price-prod'> Preço: </span>" . $row_produto['Preco_produto'] . "<label class='switch'>" . "<input class='input-check'type='checkbox' name='" . $row_produto['ID'] . " 'value='5'>" . "<span class='check round'>" . "</span>" . "</label>" . "</div>" . "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Usa algum framework ou algo do tipo?

Comment: só Bootstrap 4 se não me engano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa fazer o `echo` separando os elementos assim, por exemplo
`echo '<div>' . '</div>';` poderia ser apenas  `echo '<div></div>';` que serviria do mesmo modo e seria mais simples de se fazer, outro ponto é na parte dos atributos, inves de `echo '<input value="'.$var.'">;'` poderia ser apenas `echo '<input value='.$var.'>;'`, e também tem mais uma questão, no seu caso você queria algo mais legível, mas seria melhor você colocar tudo apenas em uma linha para poupar espaço, mas ai está o exemplo de como deveria ser:

```
echo "<div class='row border bg-color: #80006f'>
    <div class='col-2 p-3'>
      <img class='Img rounded border border-primary' src='".$pasta.$row_produto['Img_produto']."' id='produto'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-5'>
      <div class='row'>
        <span class='name-prod'>Nome: </span>" 
        .$row_produto['Nome_produto'].
         "<div class='row'>
            <span class='desc-prod-title'>Descrição:</span>" 
            .$row_produto['Descricao_produto'].
          "</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-2'>
       <span class='price-prod'>Preço:</span>" 
       .$row_produto['Preco_produto']. 
       "<label class='switch'>
         <input class='input-check'type='checkbox' name='".$row_produto['ID']."' value='5'>
         <span class='check round'></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>";
```

obs: termine de alinhar com um editor de texto como notepad++ pois este do site bagunça um pouco kkk

Comment: Deste jeito fica bem mais simples e legível mesmo, sou de fácil confundimento e deste modo fica muito melhor para eu ler o código. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Termine de alinhar com editores como notepad++ para dar os toques finais :)

Comment: pode deixar =) estou fazendo um projeto de "tcc" e não tivemos muita noção sobre php e muitas coisas sobre as quais estamos usando agora, estou tendo que aprender na marra sem ter de começar do zero poís possui data de entrega curta kk, muito obrigado sua ajuda valeu muito!

Comment: Eu tentei substituir meu código para o seu e aparece a seguinte mensagem : 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina_exposoft_2019\php\consulta.php on line 109  o que pode ser ? pois está linha 109 é uma linha vazia

Comment: Teste de novo, atualizei o código

Comment: acontece a mesma coisa =/

Comment: verifique se ficou alguma coisa sobrando do ultimo código, aqui eu testo ele e funciona normalmente, veja se ficou para trás, um ponto e virgula ou se uma chave ficou aberta

Comment: realmente, foi a chave que fecha o while... Muito obrigado, estou mt disperso. Agradeço pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar uma função que simplifique esse processo e de certo modo crie um "microframework" próprio pra trabalhar.
Cria um template padrão pras `divs`, exemplo:

```
<div class='row border'>
    <div class='col-2 p-3 '>
        <img class='Img rounded border border-primary' src='{SRC_IMG}' id='produto'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-5'>
        <div class='row'>
            <span class='name-prod'> Nome: </span>
                {NOME_PROD}
            <div class='row'>
                <span class='desc-prod-title'> Descrição:</span>
                {DESCRICAO}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-2'>
            <span class='price-prod'> Preço: </span>
            {PRECO}
            <label class='switch'>
                <input class='input-check'type='checkbox' name='{ID}' value='5'>
                <span class='check round'></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E com o `php` você faz as chamadas e substitui os valores dos campos que precisam ser trocados, exemplo:

```
<?php  
    $pasta = '../img/img_produto/';
    $imagem = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
    //$defaults = array('{SRC_IMG}', '{NOME_PROD}', '{DESCRICAO}', '{PRECO}', '{ID}');

    function montaDivs($infos){
        $html = file_get_contents('template.html'); // html criado anteriormente
        return str_replace(array_keys($infos), array_values($infos), $html);
    }
    $result_produto = "SELECT * FROM produto";
    $resultado_produto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produto);
    while($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produto)){
        $set['{SRC_IMG}'] = $pasta.$row_produto['Img_produto'];
        $set['{NOME_PROD}'] = $row_produto['Nome_produto'];
        $set['{DESCRICAO}'] = $row_produto['Descricao_produto'];
        $set['{PRECO}'] = $row_produto['Preco_produto'];
        $set['{ID}'] = $row_produto['ID'];
        echo montaDivs($set);
    }
?>
```

Com isso você pode começar aplicar traduções, adicionar campos de uma forma mais simples, tornando a manutenção do teu código bem mais fácil. Note que a base do processo está na substituição de `strings` predefinidas por valores dinâmicos do teu BD..

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
<?php while ($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produto)) { ?>
    <div>
        Aqui você pode criar elementos normalmente 
        </br>
        Pode também exibir valores assim: <?php echo $row_produto['Preco_produto']; ?>
    </div>

<?php } // Fim while ?>
```